# Was Spinosaurus bipedal or quadrupedal?

Tags: palaeontology

Different sites told me different things. I tried looking it up but I haven’t found anything. So which was it? Was Spinosaurus quadrupedal or bipedal like all other theropods? Either seems possible.

Comment: The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinosaurus#Locomotion_and_posture) is pretty thorough on the subject. Is there a particular point you needed clarifying?

Comment: Hi. According to previous research's Spinosaurus was a bipedal like other theropods while recent research conducted by Nizar Ibrahim states that Spinosaur was a quadruped